# Backbone listenTo doesnt firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new in Backbone and trying to run following code. But I don't understand somehow. It is not working properly. More clearly when I create collection listenTo doesn't catch the create event.

Here is my code

```
var levelIndex=0;
var app =  {};
$(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
  });  

  //model
  app.Level = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
          levelIndex:-1
      }
  });

  //collection
  app.Levels= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Level,
    url:'#'
  });

  //views
  app.LevelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      'click .addItems': 'addItems',
      'click .clearItems': 'clearItems',
      'click .removeLevel':'removeLevel'
    },
    addItems: function () {
      // add items
    },
    clearItems:function(){
      //
    },
    removeLevel:function(){
      //
    },
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'level active',
    template: _.template($('#levelTemplate').html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
  });

//levels view
  app.LevelsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .add': 'addLevel'
    },

    addLevel: function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('inside add level function');
      var formData = {};
      formData['levelIndex']=levelIndex++;
      this.collection.create( formData );
      console.log('after creating collection');
    },  

    el: '#levels',

    initialize: function() {

    this.collection=new app.Levels(new app.Level());
      //following line of code doesnt work properly
      this.listenTo( this.collection, 'create', this.renderLevel );
    },

    // render levels view by rendering each level in its collection
    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(function (item) {
            this.renderLevel(item);
        }, this);
    },
    // render a level by creating a LevelView and appending the
    // element it renders to the levels' element
    renderLevel: function (item) {
      var levelView = new app.LevelView({
        model: item
      });
      this.$el.append(levelView.render().el);
    }
  });
  new app.LevelsView();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no event `create` on collection or model.
In your case you want to use event `add` that fire when model added to collection.
But you'll miss one model adding, because you added first model before start listening.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

About `Collection.create()`:

> Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered on the collection, a "request" event as the new model is sent to the server, as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with the successful creation of the model. Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.